# what is equivalent Locale.US of Android in iOS

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS. In my android application, to convert milli seconds to date, Local.US is used as a Locale.  What is the equivalent function in iOS?

BTW, i am using the below code:

```
NSDate *eeDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDateFormatter *dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"];

result = [dFormatter stringFromDate:eeDate];
```

What i understood is it gets the localTimeZone set in the Mobile. But i would like to get particularly Locale.US equivalent in Android here.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is `[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]`.

To use this with `NSNumberFormatter`, try:

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSDateFormatter *dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"];
[dFormatter setLocale:usLocale];

NSString *result = [dFormatter stringFromDate:eeDate];
```